# unable to retrieve JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON data that looks like this:

```
{"id": "1", "properties": [{"shape": "circle", "color": "red"}]}
```

However, I am unable to retrieve.  I have tried:

```
return(
     shapeData.map((data, index) => {
           data.properties.map((item)=>{item.shape}
     )}
)
```

error:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Tried 2:

```
return(
         shapeData.properties.map((item)=>{item.shape}
         )
    )
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message_type' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid indeed. If you wrap an arrow function with curly braces `{`, the arrow function will not automatically return the code inside.

If you remove the curly braces (or add a return statement before the code inside) it should work:

```js
return shapeData.map((data, index) => {
  return data.properties.map((item) => item.shape);
});
```

Comment: i will get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`. however, if i were to do console.log(shapeData) before the return, i will not get null

Comment: i have added more content, not sure if it helps